# How report of reviewer travel through editorial system?

Tags: peer-review

When a reviewer submit review report through editorial system, does this report goes straight to author by mail or review report is first scrutinize by editor and then goes to author ?

Answer (score 7):

The report goes to the editor.  Once the editor has all the referee reports (if more than one reviewer is involved), the editor makes a decision about acceptance.  Then the editor sends the decision and the referee reports (which are occasionally redacted by the editor) to the author.

Comment: When all referee reports reached editor then what should be the status of manuscript, `under review`, `with editor` or `editor assigned` ?